# Query for getting average velocity

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have the following mapping in Elasticsearch:

```
PUT my_index
{
    "mappings": {
      "my_entry": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      },
        "properties": {
          "RouteId": {
            "type":"keyword"
          },
          "Date": {
            "type":"date"
          },
          "Velocity": {
            "type":"double"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I want to know the average velocity for a route with `RouteId` equal to 1. The average velocity should NOT be calculated as a mean or median because I might have the following distribution of velocity values:

[image]

Y axis: absolute frequency, X axis: range of velocity values.

Therefore I want to calculate the average velocity as the value that has the highest frequency (highest value of Y axis). For example, in the above example the range `45-50` has the highest frequency. So, the average velocity should be (45+50)/2 = 47.5.

How can I do it using query language of Elasticsearch?

**UPDATE:**

I wrote the following query, but it does not really fit my requirements. The average velocity gets skewed. I, however, want to obtain average velocity by calculating the frequency of buckets as shown in the figure above.

```
POST my_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {"term": {"RouteId": "2"}}
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs" : {
    "AvgVelocity" : { "avg" : { "field" : "Velocity" } }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all your buckets have the same size, you can use the `histogram` bucket aggregation with size 5 and the `avg` sub-aggregation. Then you can order the histogram buckets by decreasing order of the `AverageVelocity` aggregation and the first bucket at the top will be the value you're looking for.

```
{
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "filter": [
          {"term": {"RouteId": "2"}}
        ]
      }
    },
    "aggs" : {
        "prices" : {
            "histogram" : {
                "field" : "Velocity",
                "interval" : 5,
                "order" : { "AvgVelocity" : "desc" }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "AvgVelocity": {
                    "avg": {
                        "field": "Velocity"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just a small question. In your query, the ordering is done based on `AvgVelocity` value. However, the ordering should be based on `doc_count` (i.e. a bucket with the highest `doc_count` value should be on top). How can I do it?

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that it can be done by deleting `"order": { ... }`, because by default the buckets are ordered based on `doc_count` in descending order.